# solr: how to split the field into overlapping two-word phrases?

Tags: solr

Idea is to leverage two-word phrase processing.
Example:
With sufficient thrust, pigs fly just fine:

(With sufficient)
(sufficient thrust)
(thrust pigs)
(pigs fly)
(fly just)
(just fine)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [ShingleFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter):

> In: "To be, or what?"
>
> Tokenizer to Filter: "To"(1), "be"(2), "or"(3), "what"(4)
>
> Out: "To"(1), "To be"(1), "be"(2), "be or"(2), "or"(3), "or what"(3), "what"(4)

If you also set `outputUnigrams` to false, you won't get the single tokens (i.e. `To`, `be` etc. will be excluded).

There are also built-in support in the edismax handler with the parameter `pf2` and `pf3` to consider shingles of two or three tokens for scoring.